# Generate a JSON from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have to arrays which are related.

```
shortArray = ["ID-111", "ID-222"]
longArray = ["ID-111 bis", "ID-222 bis"]
```

I created them like that because I needed unique IDs in previous steps and now I must use the same color for each pair in the chart I'm drawing them.

My aim is to generate a string with this form:

```
{
    "ID-111 bis" : chart.color("ID-111"),
    "ID-222 bis" : chart.color("ID-222"),
    ...
}
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
 const result = {}
 for(const item of longArray) {
    result[item]=[];
    result[item].push({item : "chart.color(" + shortArray+ ")"});
 }
```

Which gives me this wrong output:

```
{
"ID-111 bis" :[{item: "chart.color(ID-111,ID-222)"}],
"ID-222 bis" :[{item: "chart.color(ID-111,ID-222)"}]
}
```

Any ideas what should I change?

**LATER EDIT:**

I saw many answers which are pretty similar but there is a condition that must be respected:

The second argument should **not** be in quotes.

`"ID-111 bis" : chart.color("ID-111")` - good

`"ID-111 bis" : "chart.color("ID-111")"` - bad

Comment: What you want is not valid JSON. Do you want the value to be in quotes? Also what is `actualTitle`? Why not just loop with indexer if both arrays match one to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `item`'s value instead of `actualValue` which seems to be some static value and is not dependent on `item` in your logic

**And every array item seems to be a new array**, which is not what you are looking for

```
result[item] = {item : "chart.color(" + item.split(" ")[0] + ")"};
```

Even more precisely

```
var finalValue = {};
shortArray.forEach( function(s){
   finalValue[s+" bis"] = chart.color(s); //assuming that chart.color is the function you want to invoke
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should execute the `chart.color(actualTitle)` so it will return a value, Try :

```
const result = {}

for (var i = 0; i < longArray.length; i++) 
{
  result[longArray[i]] = 'chart.color("' + shortArray[i] + '")';
  // result[longArray[i]] = chart.color(shortArray[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
shortArray = ["ID-111", "ID-222"]
longArray = ["ID-111 bis", "ID-222 bis"]

const result = {}

for (var i = 0; i < longArray.length; i++) {
  result[longArray[i]] = 'chart.color("' + shortArray[i] + '")';
  // result[longArray[i]] = chart.color(shortArray[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It looks very similar to what I want but the second argument should be ` chart.color("ID-111")` not ` "chart.color(ID-111)"`

Comment: Fixed, take a look to the updated code. else you could try the commented line

Comment: Even with the commented line `result[longArray[i]] = chart.color(shortArray[i]);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you making an array and pushing an element inside ? If you want to get layout like:

```
{
    "ID-111 bis" : chart.color("ID-111"),
    "ID-222 bis" : chart.color("ID-222"),
    ...
}
```

simply remove the `[]` part.

```
 const result = {}
 for(const item of longArray) {
    result[item] = { "item" : "chart.color(" + shortArray+ ")"});
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If both arrays have the same length:

```
shortArray = ["ID-111", "ID-222"]
longArray = ["ID-111 bis", "ID-222 bis"]

result = {}
for (var i = 0; i < longArray.length; i++) {
    result[ longArray[i] ] = "chart.color(" + shortArray[i] + ")";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/47qcrvqh/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce` function of array

```
var shortArray = ["ID-111", "ID-222"]
var longArray = ["ID-111 bis", "ID-222 bis"]

var result = longArray.reduce((res,key,index)=>{
   // Can call chart.color without quotes if that's requirement 
   res[key] = 'chart.color("'+shortArray[index]+'")';
   return res;
},{})

console.log(result)
```